# How to enable and disable a number field using a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I generate a a pair consisting of a checkbox and number field such that they are partnered with each other? (Clicking checkbox disables its partner number field)

Javascript File:

```
$(document).ready(function(){



$("input[name=check]").click(function(){

    $("input[name=number]").attr("disabled", "disabled");

});
```

});

Laravel/html file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="js/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/validator.js"></script>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    nav {
        width: 105%;
        background: #2591f5;
        min-height: 50px;
        color: white;
    }
    nav img {
        max-height: 48px;
    }
    nav * {
        float: left;
    }

    #sidebar {

        height: 95%;

            background: grey;

            overflow: hidden;

    }
    .sidebar-box-lg{
        height: 50px;
        width: 108%;
        background: #2591f5;
        margin-top: 5%;
        font-size: 16pt;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;

    }

    .sidebar-box-sm{
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #2591f5;
        margin-top: 5%;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        color: white;
        text-align: left;
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
        min-width: 50px;

    }


    .sidebar-box-sm div{

        font-size: 30px;
        margin: 10px;
        width: 10%;
        float: left;

    }

    .sidebar-box-sm:hover{

        background-color: white;
        color: #2591f5;
        transition: all 0.5s;

    }
    .sidebar-box-sm .text{

        font-size: 16px;
        width: 65%;


    }

    .header{
    background: #2591f5;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    height: 75px;
    border-bottom: 10px groove grey;

    /*background: url("logo.png") no-repeat left;  */
    background-size: 80px;
    background-position: 30px 3px;

    }
    #content-pane{





    }

    .box-lg {
        width: 40%;
        height: 150px;
        background: #2591f5;
        color: white;
        font-size: 30px;
        padding: 5px;
        float: left;
        margin: 30px;
    }

    .subtext {

        font-size: 20px;

    }

    .button-ribbon{
        background: grey;
        font-size: 15px;
        margin-left: -1%;
        position:absolute;
        padding: 10px;
        bottom:30px;
    }


</style>

@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
    <h1> Homeroom Grade </h1>

    <!-- opening the form -->
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'students/create', 'method' => 'PUT')) }}

    <table border="0" name="table1" class="SampleTables table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Last Name</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Grade</th></tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach($students as $stud)
            <tr><td>{{ $stud->LName }} </td>
            <td> {{ $stud->FName }} </td>
            <td>{{Form::checkbox("check", "$stud->Homeroom_Grade=0")}}{{Form::number("number", $stud->Homeroom_Grade, array('min' => '70', 'max' => '100') )}}</td></tr>
            <td></td>
        @endforeach
    </table>

    <!-- Save button -->
    <button> Reset </button>
    {{Form::submit('Save')}}
    <!-- Closing the form -->
    {{ Form::close() }}
@stop
```

Comment: If you provide HTML output it would be easier, but, as i can see, just two inputs are in one(same) <td>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.change()` to detect when the checkbox has been fired:

```
$("input[name=check]").change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) $(this).parent().find("input[name=number]").attr("disabled","disabled");
    else $(this).parent().find("input[name=number]").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Like above, you should check if the checkbox is `:checked` or not to set the disabled value.

Then, you can search the checkbox's `parent()` to find the correct sibling to disable.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zj88pLe6/3/

Comment: Oh, thanks for the idea, haha, but how can I do it for multiple pairs? Based on my code, if i click the any checkbox, all number fields get disabled and enabled.

Comment: @nevermind assuming there's never any added elements to the  code. I find using the `find()` more abstract and future-proof.

Comment: @jehna1, yes, it is safer.